# Sublime crashing when launched

Tags: python, macos, crash, sublimetext2

After installation of python and pygame with macports my Sublime Text 2 starts to crash after launch. Always when I try to open it I receive the error report below:

```
Process:         Sublime Text 2 [6334]
Path:            /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
Identifier:      com.sublimetext.2
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [120]

Date/Time:       2013-07-07 18:32:42.829 -0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          175720 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           21
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   21
Anonymous UUID:                      5BB7AE5B-88F2-4DF3-B5E1-C2ED1F0FBC7D

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
  Referenced from: /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: stat() failed with errno=13
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: stat() failed with errno=13
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: stat() failed with errno=13

Binary Images:
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Anyone could please help me to find the solution?

Comment: Did you happen to remove the system Python when you installed the MacPorts version?

Comment: Unfortunately my system Python was corrupted so a I needed recover my OS X. Thanks